# React router-dom passing state from parent component to child router component showing undefined in child

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Content of the parent component **App.js**, where i pass the user state to child component Book :-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Book from "./pages/Book";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      axios
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "user/self", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
        .then((res) => setUser(res.data));
    }
  }, []);

 console.log("user state in App component", user);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <NavBar user={user} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route exact path="/book/:id" render={(routeProps) => <Book user={user} {...routeProps} />} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And content of child component **Book.js** :-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Book = (props) => {
  const [user,setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}book/${props.match.params.id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        //Check if user Auth
        console.log("user props.user in Book component", props.user);
        const isAuth = props.user ? props.user.id === res.user_id : false;
          }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}
```

before the above code was working without any issue, then suddenly i noticed that props.user is undefined in child component.

Here is the result showed in console log:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your `console.log`. Your Book component is rendering prior to user fetch completing its call. This is the result of javascript's asynchronous nature and a quirk that most people miss when using React Hook's `useEffect`. The solution is simple and is a pattern you should use moving forward in all your functional components.

1. Promisify your requests (when needed). In this case, you child component is dependent on the results of your axios request to properly render. Now you attempted to resolve this by passing an axios promise in the `useEffect`. However, `useEffect`, by design, does not expect/return promises in the callback because this pattern encourages race conditions. So here is a solid workaround using `async/await`. You can apply the following to your app component and replace the `useEffect` there.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const init = async () => {
    const token = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    
    if (token) {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "user/self", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })

      setUser(data)
    }
  }

  init();
}, []);
```

1. Protect your child components from missing data. You have a couple options here that are usually coupled with a loading indicator to ensure the component always loads. This all depends on the user experience that is expected.

You can prevent the entire route from loading until the fetch finishes.

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  ...

  // apply setLoading in useEffect

  return (
    ...
    <Route exact path="/book/:id" render={(routeProps) => loading ? <h1>LOADING</h1> : <Book user={user} {...routeProps} />} />
  )
}
```

You can prevent the entire child component from rendering until fetch finishes.

```
const Book = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      
      try {
        const {user_id} = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}book/${props.match.params.id}`)
          //Check if user Auth
        console.log("user props.user in Book component", props.user);
        const isAuth = props.user ? props.user.id === user_id : false;
        setLoading(false);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    init();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort , can you provide an example how can i implement on my code

Comment: I added more examples.. this should be more than enough to get you where you need to go. GL!